# Reshaping the board in eagle

Tags: eaglecad

I want to change the shape of my board in eagle, e.g. I want to create a hexagon instead of the square. Unfortunately I only found the possibility to move the square-edges around and increasing or decreasing the size of the board, but I could not find a possibility to add or remove edges. Is it possible in eagle to reshape the board? And if yes, how can I do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Press the `Wire` button on the left menu, then select the `Dimension` layer, then draw the custom shape you wish. You will want to delete the default square shape (4 lines) via the `delete` button.

[image]

Comment: "You may want...": I don't know about Gerber, but if you send eagle boards to the PCB hose, the outer path drawn in the Dimension layer marks the outer edges of the PCB, and all paths drawn inside the outer path will be cut out. So you definitively have to remove the original rectangle. Otherwise you may end up with an empty rectangular PCB with a hexagonal hole...

Comment: I just wanted to kindly tell that old dimensions should be removed. I will change "may" with "will"

Comment: Somehow I can not find the command "Line", did you mean the command "polygon", applied on layer dimension?

Comment: sorry it is called "wire", the one selected on the above figure (on the menu part)

Comment: Ok, going to test that tomorrow (i.e. in 6 hours...)